# Exporting object in Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, web, webpack, webpack-5

I'm building a JS library with Webpack and trying to export an object.

```js
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

console.log(location.hash.replace('#', ''));

export var upstream = {
  user: {
    getUserDetails: () => {
      if (location.hash) {
        return jwt_decode(location.hash.replace('#', ''));
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my client-side code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>UpStream</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/app.js"> <!--server is up, connects fine-->
    </script>
    <script>
        console.log(upstream);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The `console.log();` statement works as intended, but I cannot access the upstream object. Any pointers?

Comment: How are you importing and using `upstream`?

Comment: Just including the script, that's working fine, but then ```console.log(upstream)``` doesn't work.

Comment: To clarify, it throws a ReferenceError: upstream is not defined.

Comment: Update your question to show exactly how are you importing `upstream`.

Comment: Being able to reference `window.upstream` or `upstream` depends on how you are outputting the code, as in your webpack configuration. Did you output `upstream` as a [Library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) with libraryTarget to 'window'?

Comment: Thanks, that worked well! I'll accept this if you answer the post, as I cannot accept a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to access `upstream` via `window` or just `upstream` you would need to ensure you specify the export as a [Library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) with `libraryTarget` of `'window'`.

Hopefully that helps!